# socket exception in Jboss

Tags: sockets, jboss

I'm getting a socket exception as follows:

```
2010-12-30 11:49:16,921 WARN  [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] Problem starting     service jboss:service=HAJNDI
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 1101; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
```

Any thoughts on why I might be getting this exception are appreciated. I can post the output of a "netstat -a" call if needed.
Thanks!

EDIT: using JBoss 4.2.3

```
netstat -a:
```

Active Connections

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1025           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1027           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1046           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1050           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1051           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2382           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:34740          FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    0.0.0.0:56339          FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:139        FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:1109       lga15s16-in-f83:https  ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:1164       fcexchange01:1098      ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:1166       fcexchange01:1098      ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:1170       fcexchange01:1098      ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:21642      channel5-02-01-snc4:http  ESTABLISHED   
  TCP    10.10.1.129:21703      channel5-02-01-snc4:http  ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:23628      fcdomsvr01:1025        ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:24585      208.51.35.200:http     ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:24609      63-233-110-210:http    ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:24737      www-10-02-snc5:http    ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25022      74.125.226.155:http    CLOSE_WAIT  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25033      lga15s16-in-f100:http  CLOSE_WAIT  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25036      a96-17-160-9:http      ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25253      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25255      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25256      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25257      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25258      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25259      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25260      a96-6-46-48:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25261      208.51.35.184:http     ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25292      a96-6-46-25:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25296      a96-6-46-25:http       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25413      fctdomsvr02:1025       ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25443      lga15s16-in-f100:http  ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    10.10.1.129:25523      lb1:http               ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1074         app:40000              ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1101         app:27015              ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5354         FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        app:1101               ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:40000        FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:40000        app:1074               ESTABLISHED  
  TCP    127.0.0.1:56342        FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:135               FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:445               FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:1025              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:1026              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:1027              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:1050              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:1051              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING   
  TCP    [::]:1433              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING   
  TCP    [::]:2382              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING   
  TCP    [::]:3389              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING   
  TCP    [::]:5357              FCBDT11:0              LISTENING   
  TCP    [::]:34740             FCBDT11:0              LISTENING  
  TCP    [::]:56339             FCBDT11:0              LISTENING   
  TCP    [::1]:56342            FCBDT11:0              LISTENING    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                       
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                     
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1434           *:*                       
  UDP    0.0.0.0:2799           *:*                        
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                      
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                        
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                          
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                      
  UDP    0.0.0.0:53087          *:*                       
  UDP    0.0.0.0:58816          *:*                       
  UDP    0.0.0.0:60517          *:*                       
  UDP    10.10.1.129:137        *:*                      
  UDP    10.10.1.129:138        *:*                       
  UDP    10.10.1.129:1900       *:*                       
  UDP    10.10.1.129:5353       *:*                      
  UDP    10.10.1.129:54713      *:*                       
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                       
  UDP    127.0.0.1:53088        *:*                      
  UDP    127.0.0.1:54714        *:*                       
  UDP    127.0.0.1:60514        *:*                       
  UDP    127.0.0.1:61263        *:*                       
  UDP    127.0.0.1:62543        *:*                       
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*                       
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*                       
  UDP    [::]:1434              *:*                       
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                      
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                       
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*                     
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                      
  UDP    [::]:58817             *:*                       
  UDP    [::]:60518             *:*                      
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                      
  UDP    [::1]:5353             *:*                      
  UDP    [::1]:54712            *:*                       
  UDP    [fe80::701d:2146:c800:f6ff%11]:546  *:*                      
  UDP    [fe80::701d:2146:c800:f6ff%11]:1900  *:*                       
  UDP    [fe80::701d:2146:c800:f6ff%11]:54711  *:*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing to bind a socket to port 1100 because that port is already in use by another process.

Try [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437), that should help you diagnose which process is listening on which port.

Comment: Probably that other process should not be using that port. how can i stop that other process - or at least see what it is?